# How can I count the number of times a value occurs in a column of a dataframe?

Tags: r, statistics

Is there a simple way of identifying the number of times a value is in a vector or column of dataframe? I essentially want the numerical values of a histogram but I do not know how to access it.

```
# sample vector
a <- c(1,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,3)

#hist
hist(a)
```

Thank you.

*UPDATE:*

On Dirk's suggestion I am using hist. Is there a better way than than specifying the range as 1.9, 2.9 etc when I know that all my values are integers?

```
 hist(a, breaks=c(1,1.9,2.9,3.9,4.9,5.9,6.9,7.9,8.9,9.9), plot=FALSE)$counts
```

Comment: thank you all for your suggestions. I don't know enough about this topic to understand the subtleties of table v hist; and found hist easiest to use, hence marked it as best answer.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try this:

```
R> a <- c(1,2,1,1,1,3,1,2,3,3)
R> b <- hist(a, plot=FALSE)
R> str(b)
List of 7
 $ breaks     : num [1:5] 1 1.5 2 2.5 3
 $ counts     : int [1:4] 5 2 0 3
 $ intensities: num [1:4] 1 0.4 0 0.6
 $ density    : num [1:4] 1 0.4 0 0.6
 $ mids       : num [1:4] 1.25 1.75 2.25 2.75
 $ xname      : chr "a"
 $ equidist   : logi TRUE
 - attr(*, "class")= chr "histogram"
R>
```

R is *object-oriented* and most methods give you meaningful results back. Use them.

Comment: I think using hist is a bad idea, because it calculates bin counts, not particular value counts.

Comment: Thanks Dirk - I understand that R is object-oriented, but I don't know how to figure out that plot=FALSE is an argument I can pass to hist, for example.

Answer (score 20):

Use `table` function.

Comment: As you were snitching about my suggestion of `hist` (even though that was what the OP asked about !!), let me mention that `table()` has a dark downside too:  ever tried it with thousands of unique values in the object you're tabulating?  ;-)   At the end of the day, both are valuable, but for different purposes.  As are `cut()`, `quantile()` etc pp

Comment: I'm happy with any method that returns the count of the number of values, and it seems that I can control the number of breaks. However I don't understand the result from hist: e.g.
hist(a, breaks=3, plot=FALSE)$counts returns 5 2 0 3

Comment: @Dirk I was not snitching; in my view using table is a generic answer and hist is an optimization for the case when the number of unique values is large; indeed fighting with bins when you have few numbers to count is not at all elegant and may be even inefficient.

Comment: @celenius This is why I prefer table.

Comment: @mbq: I didn't mean to sound so negative -- please imagine a smiley in the proper places.  `table()` *is* a good answer provided a) you have only a small-ish number of different values and b) that is in fact what you want --- where celenius seems to be after `hist()`.

Comment: @celenius: `hist()`, like many other R functions, is rich in features. If you say `breaks=3` you only say 'give me three breaks'. You could also say `breaks=seq(0,5)+0.5` to supply 0.5,1.5,2.5...,5.5 or many other forms.

Comment: @Dirc I agree; I've even gave you a vote, still this is also a wiki-like service and some more info won't hurt it. Even our small discussion can be useful for others.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to use `hist` you don't need to specify the breaks as you did, just use the `seq` function

```
br <- seq(0.9, 9.9, 1)
num <- hist(a, br, plot=F)$counts
```

Also, if you're looking for a specific value you can also use `which`.

For instance:

```
num <- length(which(a == 1))
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the performance difference between `hist` and `table` in the case of many unique values that Dirk and mbq already pointed out, I would also like to mention an other difference in functionality.

`hist$counts` will also give you zero counts for the bins that do not have any cases. This can be very valuable in the case where you want to be confident about the number of bins (bars on a barplot for example) that will end up in a following plot.

`table` on the other hand will only give you counts for existing values.

You might also want to check the `right` option of `hist` that controls whether your breaks (intervals) will be right closed or not.